# What is the difference between a texture pack and a shader?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Everyone knows what texture packs are. They make blocks look different, as set by the author of the texture pack. But now, I'm hearing about something new called a shader.

1. What is a shader?
2. How is it different from a texture pack?

Comment: Have you tried googling the word "shader"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Textures define what an object's surface will look like:
Take a wire-frame cube on which you put your own surface (texture). In context of graphics, each point is called a vertex, so a cube/block is made of 8 vertices and 6 faces.

Imagine that you have foldable tent in real life: the texture will be like the fabric that is put on the wire-frame.

Shaders on the other hand, in 3D graphics, are a description language which defines how to change texture color, lightness and other things dynamically. In graphics it is used to simulate lighting effects, depth, other things.

If you want to find out about them more and have more technical details good start is Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader
or any 3D graphics tutorial, because texture and shaders are some of the most fundamental things in 3D object rendering.

They are very different things.

What does that mean in context of Minecraft?

- Now you could not only have high quality textures on blocks, but those blocks could react to lighting (for example they could be only half-lit), or they could cast shadows on each other.
- Shaders allow for more realistic lighting modifications (imagine a colored lamp which colors the room, except where the player casts a shadow).
- It also allows more realistic water surfaces and various effects such as lens flares, depth of view, blur effects, depending how the shaders are implemented.

So in a nut-shell the answers to your questions are:

1. Shaders are short scripts that many games use to enhance their graphics, make light behave more realistically, objects change color, simulate refraction, add stylistic chocies (e.g. Borderlands' black outlines), etc.
2. No, they are not comparable. Textures are pre-rendered images applied to the faces of 3D models (in this case, blocks), while shaders work with and affect what the textures will ultimately look like on your screen, depending on various conditions, such as nearby light sources. In other games it is what makes swords shine and water look realistic.

Comment: A Shader is not actually "property set" (you seem to be missing an 'a') or "properties", but a script/program defining instructions on how to process input. While largely used for lighting calculations, shaders are also leveraged in many other ways. For example, screen-space shaders provide various screen effects and shaders can also be used for other kinds of processes such as animating textures.

Comment: You are correct, I just wanted to show that it operates on dynamic properties of an image.

Comment: @OrcJMR I've just made some edits and have clarified that.